# Is there any risk to transfer an application from JRE 5 to 8?

Tags: java

I want to tranfer a web application from JRE 5 to 8. I know JRE is backward compatible. So does that mean I don't need to worry at all? I'm not sure if the transfer is absolutely safe, or there will be a chance that some unexpected problems (such as performance problems) will emerge.

Comment: It is mostly backward compatible, but as some bugs get fixed, behaviour changes. So code that did compile with Java 5 may not compile with Java 8 or may have a different behaviour.

Comment: There's no way to know what is in your code that may or may not break without really analyzing it.  I say try it and see.

Comment: @assylias In my opinion, backward compatible means the code written in Java 5 will completely compile with 8. Can you give me an example about the different behaviour you said?

Comment: @Dodd10x My application is an online server. I want to make sure the transfer is completely safe and doing tests case by case may cost lots of time.

Comment: I saw Java8, I gave it a try. It throw compile error in one of the comments. I gave up.

Comment: @roll1987 doing tests for any reason takes a lot of time. that's why you need to automate your tests. how come you are so concerned with risk and "completely safe", yet do not have automated tests?? Sounds like a big contradiction to me.

Comment: @assylias It's definitely possible for code to not compile during this migration.  Something I've seen for myself is that we had an implementation of `java.sql.ResultSet` in Java 5.  This interface had additional methods added in Java 6 - so our implementation did not implement all of the methods in the interface (and wasn't abstract), which is a compile error in Java 6.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes, doing tests is necessary.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle That's interesting, which means JRE is not completely backward compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Java is backwards compatible, but there are security issues you might have with newer versions of Java.

Comment: And security issue that might be fixed by newer versions too!

Comment: What kind of security issues? Could you give me some examples please?

Comment: Modern JRE's require signed jars and stuff. I had an applet that worked fine a couple of years ago but suddenly stopped working because it wasn't signed...

Answer (score 1):

Yes certainly there are risks at this earlier stages, which may needs thorough testing. You also need to ensure, if all your other dependencies, frameworks, servers, etc all supports JRE 8.

Just a few example,

```
- Weblogic Server does not yet support JRE 8
- In Eclipse you won't find the compiler level 1.8, easily after setting JRE to 8. You may need to do work around by installing some plugins.
```

It may take little time when it would be supported by all tools.